# Force Move to a new view controller (without segue)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I'm making an app on xcode with swift 3 and am making the app have multiple variables. I want my app to test when a certain variable is at a value, move to a new view controller no matter what view you are on. I know i can use segues but with a lot of views this gets messy. Is there anything i can use that just uses code or is a lot simpler.
Thanks

Comment: Your variable's value will on which condition and the variable's value remain same for all viewControllers?

Comment: Yes the Variable will be the same and updated over all views

Answer (score 0):

You can use property's `didSet` and present the view controller.

```
class TestVC : UIViewController {
    var variable: Int = 10 {
        didSet {
            if variable == 20 {
                present(someVC, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeVC : UIViewController {
    func didFinishWhatever() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try that code where i put the view controllers name in the present bit it says "cannot convert value of type 'TestViewController.type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'"

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `extension` of `UIViewController` and in there whenever your variable's value change simple push/present your required `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyBoard try these lines of code:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeVCIdentifier")
 self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```